# What is the gramatical foundation for "both of which" in the following sentence

Tags: grammar, clauses

> Doctors prescribed antacids (which reduce stomach acid) to patients
>   and instructed them to modify their lifestyle and eating habits, both
>   of which resulted in little success.

Source:https://brilliant.org/practice/skeptical-empiricism/?p=3

I can understand the meaning of the sentence, but if I were to construct the sentence myself, my first attempt would be :

> Doctors prescribed antacids to patients and instructed them to modify their lifestyle and eating habits, which **both resulted in little success.**

My question is:

1. Does my sentence contain grammar mistake? If so, what's the problem?
2. What's the name of the clause the original sentence used?

Comment: **which both** is not idiomatic.  *She made several suggestions, **some of which** were quite good.*  You wouldn't say **which some**.  The relative pronoun **which** is enlisted in a partitive construction.

Comment: You can also say *...several suggestions **of which some** were quite good*

Comment: Both are fine and just two different ways of saying the same thing. "Both of which resulted in little success" and "which both resulted in little success" are supplementary relative clauses. In both cases, "which" has the entire preceding clause as antecedent.

Comment: @BillJ: Would you also accept **...which a few were successful** and **...which neither were successful.** and **...which some were successful.**  and **...which many were successful**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How pronouns or nouns can be used to specify parts of numbers and or amounts.

Numbers and amounts in relation to some greater number or amount be described using: **some, none, a few, a couple, each, both (for two only)** etc. Those are nouns or pronouns.

If you want to specify: some number or amount out of some total, you can use **of**:

- Ten books were chosen. **Eight of them** were in Spanish.

If you decide to make one sentence of that, you can use:

- Five books were chosen, **eight of which** were in Spanish.

**Which** introduces a relative clause.

I would argue that: **both of which** is standard for this usage. In that sense, it works like all the other nouns or pronouns for numbers and amounts:
- **both of which, two of which, some of which, none of which, a couple of which**. etc.

while the second option: "which **both** resulted in little success" means the same thing for most people, but one could argue, if one wants to be persnickety,  "which both" should apply to two things that follow:

**Thus, it is no surprise that within a five-year period, the fiscal figures produced by Greece underwent two major revisions, **which both** resulted in an increase in the reported budget deficit and debt.** [example where the word both is followed by two noun phrases](https://vasilissarafidis.wordpress.com/2018/10/24/the-tragedy-of-greek-statistics/)

That can also be written:
Thus, it is no surprise that within a five-year period, the fiscal figures produced by Greece underwent two major revisions, **which** resulted **both** in an increase in the reported budget deficit and debt.**

Please note: though some people commonly think that the two are the same, they are not formally exactly the same. If they were the same, the pattern could be used with other amounts and numbers:

- Two books were chosen, **both of which** were in Spanish.
- Two books were chosen, which both were in Spanish. [not really grammatical and makes no sense semantically.]
  OR
- Two boys ran the race, both of whom were lousy students.
- Two boys ran the race, who both were lousy students. [accepted]

If one looks **at the second sentence** above, "which both" can sound funny.

It is harder to "hear" in the sentence below:
- Two books were chosen for the prize both of which resulted in great success.
- Two books were chosen for the prize which both resulted in great success.

Whereas:
- Two books were chosen for the prize which both resulted in great success and high sales. There ***both*** is an adverb that goes with the verb result.

In my opinion, therefore, **both of which resulted in** is better than **both which resulted in**, as **"both which" can be shown to fit another formal pattern**, but I do accept many people will say are exactly the same. **I say people see them as having exactly the same meaning but that if that were formally true, then, other nouns and pronouns could be used the same way and they cannot.**

Sample of non-grammatical use: which none resulted in, which some resulted in, etc. Thus, if you accept "which both resulted in", which is fine, it is an anomaly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I would understand the meaning of the sentence outside of its context.  It helps to know the passage is about how peptic ulcers are not related to acid levels in the stomach, and that the overall passage is part of a quiz designed to test your ability to be skeptical and spot empirical errors.

There's really nothing wrong with "both of which" clause except that it's slightly ambiguous.  We don't know if applies to *both* antacid use and diet/lifestyle change or just to diet and lifestyle change.  The first is certainly more *logical* than the second, but a well-constructed sentence should be perfectly clear.

In your version "which both" is less idiomatic but is grammatical, but the sentence does nothing to resolve the ambiguity.  A better choice would be to restructure the sentence as a *list* of attempted remedies, and then use *none* to include them all:

> Doctors prescribed antacids, instructed their patients to reduce stress in their lives, and suggested their patients modify their eating habits, **none of which** resulted in much success.

As Tᴚoɯɐuo mentions in his comment, this structure might be a [*partitive construction*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partitive), although since it includes *all* of the elements it much just be a common *subordinate clause*.